# Puedo usar mi ImageView (imageViewfoto1) como botón para iniciar la cámara y al tomar la foto visualizarla en el mismo ImageView (imageViewfoto1)?

Tags: android-studio

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.mx.org.christian.stackflow.MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewfoto1"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_camera_android"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageViewfoto2" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewfoto2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_camera_android"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Claro que se puede, pero que has realizado en esto, simplemente usa un listener para activar la camara y en esa misma instancia ImageView agregar la imagen.

Comment: Jorgesys♦ Gracias, podrias indicarme de algún ejemplo que pueda usar o leer en algún sitio. Soy novato y no encuentro un ejemplo claro. Para que el mismo ImageView Encienda la Camara, tomé foto y la muestre en el mismo ImageView. Los ejemplos siempre tienen un boton + ImageView. Gracias